# Getting Google Drive to automatically restart syncing after disconnecting external harddrive

Tags: external-hard-drive, automation, google-drive

I have my Google Drive folder on my external hard drive as my internal is a tiny SSD. This setup works fine as long as my hard drive remains plugged in all the time my computer is on. If it is unplugged I have to go into drive settings and select the drive folder again to resume syncing. This is quite irritating to be doing on a daily basis so I was hoping there would be a way to automate it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way that you can link the Google Drive folder to your SSD? Is the SSD ***really*** that tiny to where you have no space? That would keep the auto-sync on. How much space do you have on the SSD?

Comment: I have maybe 15GB on my SSD but my drive library contents are 200GB+

Comment: The AutoIT solution sounds like the sort of thing that I'm looking for but I don't have the time to learn a whole API to fix it. If someone is familiar with this tool or something similar and could make a script that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I setup **Google Drive** on a test PC with an external hard drive just to emulate this issue and figured out the logic to use with [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to complete the **Google Drive** folder location link once the external drive comes back online, etc.

### E Drive For Me

In my case the external drive is assigned the "E" drive letter and the **Google Drive** folder is right on the root of this drive so this is where I needed to point **Google Drive** when it lost connection.

[image]

### Take Note

I did have to take note of the number of <kbd>**`Tab`**</kbd>, , and  keys I had to press before landing on the `E:\GoogleDrive` folder before pressing the <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd> key from within the <kbd>**`Locate folder...`**</kbd> button from the **Google Drive** error window that indicates ***"Your Google Drive folder is missing"*** so I could incorporate that into the [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) logic and the [Send](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) functions.

What this means for you is that you will need to make the error message pop up, then wait for your external drive to come back up, and then press the <kbd>**`Locate folder...`**</kbd> button from the **Google Drive** error message. Now, be sure to NOT touch the mouse and just press the <kbd>**`Tab`**</kbd>, , and  keys until you land on your Google Drive folder on the external drive.

Be sure to take note of ***the order and the number of times you pressed each of those to get to this folder***. Once on the folder you just press <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd> and it'll sync back up, etc. In order to automate this, you'll need to put in this effort and adjust the logic accordingly which I'll explain below and should be quite easy to complete and understand.

[image]

### The AutoIT Logic

Here's the logic I used in my case to get the **Google Drive** folder linked back up.

```
If WinExists("Google Drive", "Your Google Drive folder is missing") Then
      Sleep(300)
      WinActivate("Google Drive", "Your Google Drive folder is missing")
      Sleep(300)
      Send("{TAB 2}")
      Send("{Enter}")
      Send("{TAB 2}")
      Send("{DOWN 3}")
      Send("{RIGHT 1}")
      Send("{DOWN 1}")
      Send("{ENTER}")
EndIf
```

### Logic Clarification

The numerical digit within the `Send("{<key> <#>}")` will represent the number of times that key is pressed back to back so `Send("{TAB 99}")` will press the <kbd>**`Tab`**</kbd> key 99 times and then move onto the logic or function, etc. beneath that in order.

You could very well have `Send("{TAB}")` and then have it again beneath that line on 98 more lines to complete the same task. Just note that if there is a number after the key within the [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) function then that key is pressed that many time before it moves on to the next logic to press.

[image]

### Notable Items

The logic I used expects the **Google Drive** error window to be up in order for it to work so you can either wait for that to pop up or else easily get it to pop up by left clicking on the taskbar **Google Drive** error exclamation icon and then selecting the `Error - Google Drive folder is missing` with one left click at which point the **Google Drive** error window will pop up and the [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) logic should run and take action once executed.

[image]
[image]

### Why AutoIT

[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is free and it allows you to compile an executable file, and once compiled it will run on Windows whether you have [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) installed on that machine or not. I actually never install [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and I always use the portable version and then copy over the executable to the machines I need to run the correlated logic against.

---

### Further Resources

- [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)
- [WinExists](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinExists.htm)
- [WinActivate](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm)
- [Send](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm)

Comment: This is spot on. Thank you. I'll have to tweak the details but I'm sure I can figure the rest out from here.

Answer (score 0):

When the external drive is removed, Google Drive reports the error "Your Google Drive folder is missing". The [Official Google Help page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2565956#missing) describes how to fix that error, but I'm afraid it's all manual (click the error message and then the "Locate Folder" button).

Maybe your problem can be solved in another way? Do you know why your external drive is getting disconnected? If it happens when you restart your computer, you could try stopping Google Drive from starting automatically. Then you could start Google Drive after your external drive has already been connected.

Comment: It's me disconnecting it. I have to periodically remove my hard drive several times a day because of the way I work. I've been doing the manual process but don't know whether I could automate it with some script triggered by plugging in the harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Insync Google Drive client](https://www.insynchq.com/) ($29.99 with 15 days trial).

For using Insync, see the article
[Sync your external or network drives to Google Drive with Insync’s “Plug-n-sync”](https://medium.com/@insync/sync-your-external-or-network-drive-to-google-drive-with-plug-n-sync-2d6c374e8ac2).

Insync will detect an unplugged drive :

[image: unplugged]

Syncing will resume automatically as soon as you plug back that external drive:

[image: replugged]