# sendkeys "{TAB}" is being ignored

Tags: microsoft-excel, vbscript

I've created a .VBS file with the code seen below.

It works fine if I use it to fill in any form in a browser, and also works with Excel and Notepad.

However, it gives an error when used on an application installed on my system. The entire text is entered in a single cell. `sendkey "{TAB}"` doesn't work in this application.

Also, if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after using this, it moves to the previous cell instead of the next cell. The Shift key gets stuck there because of CAPITAL text I think.

Also, NUM LOCK key off sometimes while using this.

Can any one help with this?

```
set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wScript.Shell")
wscript.sleep 700
wshshell.sendkeys "TYPE TEXT 1"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "{TAB}"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "TYPE TEXT 2"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "{TAB}"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "TYPE TEXT 3"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "{TAB}"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "TYPE TEXT 4"
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "{TAB}"
wscript.sleep 400
```

Comment: Try `wshshell.sendkeys vbTab`

Comment: As an experiment, please try inserting a `DoEvents` command before and after each `wshshell.sendkeys "{TAB}"` command

Comment: @BillHileman wshshell.sendkeys vbTab - didn't worked

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Tried with DoEvents, it doesn't work also it doesn't type all text it typed only TYPE TEXT 1. after that nothing happen

Comment: What is the program you are having issues with? You mentioned it works in Notepad and Excel.

Comment: @davidmneedham I have issue with "citrix idc distiller"

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I already tried with "wshshell.sendkeys "{TAB}", True" it also doesn't worked

Comment: I see your issue running in Excel over Citrix. See this [Stack Overflow question identifying the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028872/sendkeys-alternative-that-works-on-citrix).

Comment: Not sure if this would help any but another potential easy thing to try just in case ... https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html—activate by title and then see if the tab goes or not... Easy enough to rule out with the solution you are currently using I suppose.

Comment: @davidmneedham I saw this post before posting my question. I doesn't have access for setting or to change any other internal codes. Also I doesn't have any other version to test. I have access to a form only, which I have to fill, like a data entry project. For that I have created this script with which I can fill that form just with a click.

I tested with browsers for signing up in a website its working there fine, but only in this software I am having issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SendKeys apparently doesn't work with Citrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028872/sendkeys-alternative-that-works-on-citrix).

An alternative solution to using VBScript is to use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/). This ahk script worked for me in Citrix:

```
Sleep 700
SendInput TYPE TEXT 1
Sleep 400
SendInput {TAB}
Sleep 400
SendInput TYPE TEXT 2
Sleep 400
SendInput {TAB}
Sleep 400
SendInput TYPE TEXT 3
Sleep 400
SendInput {TAB}
Sleep 400
SendInput TYPE TEXT 4
Sleep 400
SendInput {TAB}
Sleep 400
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have used AHK scripts, but I'm not allowed to use outside software. I have tested with ahk it work totally fine, but not with wscripts. I am not able to track why SendInput works & sendkeys not.

Comment: @SahilManuja How about with AutoIT? I ask only because it does NOT require it to be installed to run an executable file that can do the same? From what I recall with AHK, you have to install the program to use its scripts; however, with AutoIT, you can compile an exe and then put it on a USB thumb drive, and then run it from there and it can take advantage of some of those same keyboard emulation features. Here's an answer example I wrote if you want to see: https://superuser.com/questions/1220290/getting-google-drive-to-automatically-restart-syncing-after-disconnecting-extern/1221599#1221599

Comment: AutoHotkey has the same ability. It can be run from a portable installation or it can be compiled to an EXE.

Comment: Yes it worked, but it create 1mb file which is too large & I have to create files in 1000's. Also there is no option for bulk convert from ahk - exe

Any other option?

Comment: [ahk2exe](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) can be used in the commandline in bulk. But it would be possible to create an AHK file to read in the commands needed to be sent to avoid creating thousands of separate EXEs.

Comment: But file size will be 1MB or more, where as the scrip which I created .vbs is just 1kb

Comment: @SahilManuja I'd take a stab at AutoIT then perhaps as I don't recall simple keyboard key stroke functions being very large at all and you can run from the same one executable via a UNC path or something like `\\server\share\script\CitrixKeyApp.exe` on all the client machine or whatever you are doing—perhaps you can do the same with the AHK compiled executable but a 1 MB compiled file to run simple logic seems a bit too big IMO. [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?autoit3/autoit-v3.zip) is FREE and portable too by the way.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your help, Created exe file with AKH with below code. Data was in excel so created a search button in it, search will give single result and then hyper link a cell with exe which will auto copy paste in citrix with alt tab function

X1 := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")

X1.Range("C5").Select

sleep, 1000

SendInput ^c

sleep, 250

send {ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}

sleep, 250

SendInput ^v

sleep, 250

SendInput {tab}

sleep, 250

send {ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}

sleep, 1000

SendInput {tab}

SendInput ^c

sleep, 250